# How can I pass this table from SQL Server to Postgress?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Does anyone know how I can make a generated column in Postgres?

This is the code in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRICE]
(
    [ISIN] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Nemo] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Month(t)] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month(t-1)] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Month(t-2)] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

I searched the internet and found that the way to do it in Postgres is by using `GENERATE ALWAYS AS` but I get an error because the month column is repeated several times, that is the question that is supposed to be differentiated when doing the subtraction.

```
CREATE TABLE PRICE
(
    ISIN varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Nemo varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Month int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (t) STORED,
    Month int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (t-1) STORED,
    Month int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (t-2) STORED,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't generated columns, they just have non-standard names that need quoted identifiers. In SQL Server such a column needs to be enclosed in square brackets. Postgres follows the SQL standard where such names need to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE PRICE (
  ISIN varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  Nemo varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "Month(t)" int NOT NULL,
  "Month(t-1)" int NOT NULL,
  "Month(t-2)" int NOT NULL
)
```

[Example with SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/-imuhGk_)

[Example with PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/_IJw2IHq)

Answer (score 1):

postgres has a different syntax, You refer the column by name and create new columns.

[`Reference`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)

```
CREATE TABLE PRICE(
    ISIN varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Nemo varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Month int,
    Month_1 int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (Month-1) STORED,
    Month_2 int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (Month-2) STORED
);
```

---

**Testing**

```
insert into PRICE values('aaa','bbb',20)
select * from price;
```

| isin | nemo | month | month_1 | month_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | 20 | 19 | 18 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)